# SWIFT: Difficultly displaying data in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am attempting to display data from Parse onto the following tableView controller. For some reason, the data is not displaying on the tableView (i.e. the rows are blank). I do not think that the data queried from Parse is being appended to the arrays. I am wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the current output:

[image]

I am using a custom prototype cell with identifier "CellTrack" class "TrackTableViewCell" and as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Here is my code in the TableViewController file:

```
 import UIKit
 import Parse

 class MusicPlaylistTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var usernames = [String]()
var songs = [String]()
var dates = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"PlaylistData")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {

                self.usernames.removeAll()
                self.songs.removeAll()
                self.dates.removeAll()

                for object in objects {

                    let username = object["username"] as? String

                        self.usernames.append(username!)
                        print("added username")


                    let track = object["song"] as? String

                        self.songs.append(track!)


                    let date = object["createdAt"] as? String

                        self.dates.append(date!)



                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

        } else {

            print(error)
        }
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return usernames.count
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTrack", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TrackTableViewCell

    cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
    cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row]
    cell.CreatedOn.text = dates[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

 }
```

And here is my code in the "TrackTableViewCell.swift" class:

```
import UIKit

class TrackTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var songTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var CreatedOn: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: Try to set breakpoints to debug. And show us which code block is never hit.

Comment: It's interesting.  I added breakpoints beside: 1) query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in; 2) self.usernames.append(username!).  None of them were executed when I selected the screen in question.  Should these queries even be in viewWillAppear?

Comment: In addition to some of the suggestions already offered, also move your call to tableView.reload() to outside the for-loop ... you should only invoke that function once you are done with assigning the tableView's lists.

Comment: @BonanzaDriver great suggestion.  I did what you suggested, however, the query code is not even executing at this point.

Comment: I don't believe the `viewWillAppear` is never hit, haha

Comment: Are you setting delegate and datasource correctly for your table view?

Comment: Are you sure you have data? Maybe your `objects` array is empty or nil?

Comment: @Abhinav yes, I am using a TableViewController and the datasource and delegate is setup correctly.

Comment: @whyceewhite the data is in Parse (and yes, there is sample date).  The issue is that when the view controller is called, it doesn't run the query and append the data items into the arrays defined in this class.  I'm sure it's something really small that I'm missing.

Comment: The general pattern is 1) query data on background thread, 2) assign the results to a "list" property, 3) on the main UI thread invoke tableView.reloadData() ....... as long as you've set your TableView delegates properly you should begin to see numberOfSection() ... numberOfRows() ... cellForRowAtIndexPath() ..... the various TableView API method firing.  If not, throw some println's in there and make sure your assumption are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your `tableView.reloadData()` in main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
   self.tableViewCell.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: According to https://parse.com/questions/what-thread-does-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-complete-on, Parse callbacks *are* executed on the main thread, so this should not be necessary.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what "main thread" is?  I basically replaced what I had before (i.e. "self.tableView.reloadData()" after the append IF STATEMENTS), with what you provided above.

Comment: I guess the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` execute in background thread, and if you want to update your UI, you must execute the UI code in main thread. But, as @MartinR recommended above, it has already run on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a guard let to see if those values are actually coming back as string or not. My guess would be that the value for created at never came back. Try it out and let me know.

```
   guard let username = object["username"] as? String else { 
   print ("could not get username") 
   }

   self.usernames.append(username)
   print("added username")

   guard let track = object["song"] as? String else {
   print ("could not get song") 
   return 
   }
   self.songs.append(track)

   guard let date = object["createdAt"] as? String else {
   print ("could not get createdAt")
   return}

   self.dates.append(date!)
```

Answer (score 0):

> `func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_ identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?`
>
> Return Value
>
> A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier or nil if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTrack", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TrackTableViewCell

  if cell == nil {
    // create a new cell here
    cell = TrackTableViewCell(...)
  }

  cell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]
  cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row]
  cell.CreatedOn.text = dates[indexPath.row]

  return cell
}
```